# How to display data from mysql database in X-editable select based on data-attribute

Tags: php, mysql

```
$('#employee_data_leadstoassign').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.assignedTo',
    url: "gmupdate.php",
    title: 'assignedTo',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    source: [ <?php  
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY name");
        while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
            result[]=array('value': $option['code'], 'text': $option['name']);
        }  
        echo json_encode($result);              
    ?>
]});
```

In this above code am fetching values from MySQL database in the array. but is not working. it's showing syntax error unexpecting ). here what's wrong with this above code?

Comment: You have the wrong syntax for key value array.

Comment: `result[]` isn't valid PHP unless you add a `$` before: `$result[]`. But that's just one of more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for key value arrays:

```
while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
  $result[]= array('value'=> $option['code'], 'text'=> $option['name']);
}
```

**My Suggestions:**

Reorganize your code, do not mix PHP and JavaScript. Start with php then print the data later.

```
<?php  
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY name");
    $result = array();
    while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
        $result[]=array('value' => $option['code'], 'text' => $option['name']);
    }             
?>

$('#employee_data_leadstoassign').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.assignedTo',
    url: "gmupdate.php",
    title: 'assignedTo',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    source: <?php echo json_encode($result);?>
});
```

Comment: I tried above code. it's showing fatal error. Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: @jacklin - What more did the error say? Should it really be `source: [<?php echo json_encode($result);?>]` and not just `source: <?php echo json_encode($result);?>`? Otherwise, it would result in: `[[{key: foo, value: bar}, {...}]]`

Comment: Looks like I had reintroduced the error in my editing. Now it is fixed.

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("select * from login");
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $result[]=array('value' => $row['userId'], 'text' => $row['name']);
    }             
?>   

$('#employee_data_leadstoassign').editable({
    container: 'body',
    selector: 'td.assignedTo',
    url: "gmupdate.php",
    title: 'assignedTo',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    source: [<?php echo json_encode($result);?>],

Comment: i tried in mysql also. but i am not sure my mysql code is correct or not. in that select option its not fetching values. but no errors. @Ibu

Comment: remove the `[ brackets ]` from the source.

Comment: @ibu. you are great. Thank you so much.  i removed [] and at the end, i added,(cpma) it's working now.    like this: source:<?php echo json_encode($result);?>,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mixed javascript with php code, that caused php yields syntax error:

```
result[]=array('value': $option['code'], 'text': $option['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong notation in PHP key value  array  use `=>` instead of `:`

```
    $('#employee_data_leadstoassign').editable({
      container: 'body',
      selector: 'td.assignedTo',
      url: "gmupdate.php",
      title: 'assignedTo',
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      source: [ <?php  $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY name");
            while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
          $result[]=array('value' => $option['code'], 'text' =>  $option['name']);}  echo json_encode($result);              
        ?>
    ]});
```

and as suggested  by  Magnus Eriksson in comment check for real souce result coulbe the []  around the result from PHO are alreay adde by json_encode   also remamber that  in php you use $result[] and not result[]

Comment: The `[` and `]` around the PHP code should probably also be removed. The `json_encode()` will add them as well. Also, don't forget the `$` in front of `result[]`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  .. valid suggestion  .. answer updated  with your suggetion too

Comment: ya. i removed brackets []. Its working fine now. thank you @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

You have to type '$' before result[]=array....

Also, '=>' must be used instead of ':'

```
$result[] = array('value' => $option['code'], 'text' => $option['name']);
```